# Changing fontFamily in native base library of react native does not work

Tags: react-native, fonts, native-base

I am using native-base library in react native. I have done following steps to change font but it does not work:

1. I pasted `myfont.ttf` in this directory:

   `node_modules/native-base/Fonts`
2. I went to the following directory:

   `node_modules/native-base/src/theme/variables/...`

   and changed all font families into `myFont.ttf` in all three files (commonColor.js, material.js and platform.js)

Please help me in this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have to first eject NativeBase's theme, you can do that by
   following [the docs
   here](http://docs.nativebase.io/Customize.html#theaming-nb-headref).
2. Then, add font to Android and iOS respectively, [this
   article](https://medium.com/react-native-training/react-native-custom-fonts-ccc9aacf9e5e)
   shows a good guide on how to do that.
3. Lastly, you can update the theme with your custom font on `./native-base-theme/variables/<theme-you-use>.js`, also describe on [the same docs above](http://docs.nativebase.io/Customize.html#theaming-nb-headref)

Comment: Did you get an error? Or isit something else? You can update your changed code on your question so we can help

Comment: I do not get any error. I just see no changes in fonts.

Comment: Have you include the `<StyleProvider style={getTheme(material)}>` as described in Nativebase's docs i shared above? You need to either wrap your whole app with it, or just the component you want to change the theme. Maybe you can share this part of your code

Comment: Yes I did. But it just changes <Text> font and It cannot change floating textInput  , and drop-down menu texts font.

Comment: You can go to `./native-base-theme/component/<any-comoponent>.js` to change its style if it doesnt behave like you wish to

Comment: But Now I could do this directly :  <Item floatingLabel style={{borderColor: '#247ba0'}}>
                                <Label style={{color: '#000000',fontFamily:'myFont'}}>Name</Label>
                                <Input/>
                            </Item>

Comment: Cool! If this works for you, you can also go to `./native-base-theme/component/Label.js` and add `fontFamily: variables.fontFamily`, so you wont have to repeatedly change the font on every label :)

Comment: But for drop-down it does not fix.

Comment: Checkout http://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#picker-def-headref and find Configuration. There are alot of different style you can customise

Comment: Oh!!! Thank you my friend. I added _fontFamily: variables.fontFamily_ as you said and it works. Maybe I could do something like this for drop-down too.

Comment: You're welcome. Looking on the docs, Picker's text style is probably on `component/Item.js`

Comment: Happy to help :)